# Using the letter $P$ to represent an event

Tags: probability, statistics

It is known that in statistics $P(X)$ represents the probability of $X$. My question, is it WRONG to use the letter $P$ to represent an event, where $P(P)$ represents the probability of $P$.

For example, let $P$ represent the event that having Pizza for dinner. Then, $P(P)$ represents the probability of having pizza for dinner.

In summary, is the letter $P$ reserved or not such that we can use it to represent general events?

Comment: Its confusing but do what you like if you can make people understand. It helps if you type mathematics properly, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I agree, but would that be considered a mathematical mistake or not?

Comment: there is nothing strictly wrong about doing something that people can't understand easily

Comment: If you have a binomial distribution in which the success probability is denoted $p,$ then you might have $\mathsf{P}(P|p).$ Especially in beginning books it is important to use notation that is not likely to be confusing, so I'd consider using $P$ for an event to be a pedagogical mistake, but not forbidden.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/470666/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not WRONG to use $P$ to represent an event. It would be easier to read and understand if you chose, say, $p$ instead to differentiate between the probability function $P$ and the event $p$. But, strictly speaking, there is nothing mathematically incorrect about representing an event with $P$.